# Had been or was?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Which sentence is correct and why?

> Beckham hasn't had an injury in 3 years btw, but we all appreciate the fact you consider he **was** either playing in another dimension or dead after he left Milan

or

> Beckham hasn't had an injury in 3 years btw, but we all appreciate the fact you consider he **had been** either playing in another dimension or dead after he left Milan

Comment: That's what I first felt about it, that both are correct and basically interchangeable taking into account what I wanted to communicate. The difference being that simple past differs from past perfect continuous in, interestingly enough, continuity.I really needed to be reassured about it, I really appreciate your reply, Mike :)

Comment: Related question, [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another). If you use [the search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=past+simple+past+perfect), you will find more related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct and both express the same information, but there are subtle nuances between them.

The first one, using *was... playing*, is in the simple past tense; the second one, using *had been... playing*, is in the past perfect progressive tense. The second one expresses the sentiment that Beckham was "playing in another dimension, but then he stopped." The first is a little more indistinct: "he was playing in another dimension, and maybe he still is."

Bottom line: either one is acceptable.